# Time plus minutes

Tags: android

I have a bunch of data containing a time value, e.g. 09:30am, and a duration, either 15,30,45 or 60. What would be the best way of getting the end time from these values? Will it be some use of a Date / Calendar or would just a custom function be quicker to do?

Comment: so if you have duration 60 and time  `09:30am` result should be `09:31am`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Joda Time library (http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) is popular, easy to work with, and handles these kinds of calculations in a straight-forward manner.

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2013, 10, 15, 9, 30); // create a DateTime representing Oct 15, 2013 at 9:30
Duration dur = Duration.standardMinutes(15); // create a duration of 15 minutes
DateTime calc = start.plus(dur); // add; result is 9:45 on 10/15/2013
```

Comment: I'll take a look at Joda now, I've seen a few people mentioning it.

Answer (score 1):

The standard java/android way for this is to use a calendar:

```
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); // now

    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 10); // add 10 days
```

There are other constants if you want to add minutues, years, seconds, ....

Answer (score 0):

Check out this solution: [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

You may need to change the `"MMMM d, yyyy"` portion to fit your data set.

Here is the Javadoc: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

edit: For the second part of your question, there are several questions on here about how to add to a Date/Calendar object.